# Can updating an Activity from MediaBrowserService cause the Service to crash?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, android-mediasession

I have an audio app with a `MediaBrowserService`. To update the `SeekBar` in the `Activity`, I have a `Runnable` in the service that updates the `MediaSession` extras every 250 milliseconds (this is to ensure the `SeekBar` movement isn't janky).

Everything works fine except a small number of users are reporting that after a couple of minutes the playback consistently cuts out. The logs don't show that `onDestroy` or `onPause` or `onStop` of the `MediaSessionCompat.Callback` is called or any of the error handling. It just stops. However, I'm unable to recreate it myself. Once the audio starts there is nothing running in the service but this. Is it possible updating the `SeekBar` this way is causing the playback to stop?

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {

    private Handler mMediaHandler;
    private MediaSessionCompat mMediaSessionCompat;
    private ExoPlayer player;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        
        mMediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(this, MediaPlayerService.class.getSimpleName());
        mMediaSessionCompat.setCallback(mMediaSessionCallback);
    }
        
    public void PlayAudio()
    {
        player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
        player.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(uri), position);
        player.prepare();
        player.play();
        
        mMediaHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        mMediaHandler.post(mUpdateMediaPosition);
    }
        
    Runnable mUpdateMediaPosition = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            final Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putInt("position", player.getCurrentPosition());
            mMediaSessionCompat.setExtras(extras);

            mMediaHandler.postDelayed(this, 250);
        }
    };
}

public class MediaActivity 
{
    private MediaBrowserCompat mMediaBrowserCompat;
    private MediaControllerCompat mMediaController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
          mMediaBrowserCompat = new MediaBrowserCompat(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                new ComponentName(mContext, MediaPlayerService.class),
                                mMediaBrowserCompatConnectionCallback,
                                getIntent().getExtras());
                        mMediaBrowserCompat.connect();
    }

    MediaControllerCompat.Callback mMediaControllerCompatCallback = new MediaControllerCompat.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onExtrasChanged(Bundle extras) {
            super.onExtrasChanged(extras);

            int position = extras.getInt("position");

            seekBar.setProgress(position);
        }
        
    }

    MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback mMediaBrowserCompatConnectionCallback = new MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConnected() {
            super.onConnected();

            mMediaController = new MediaControllerCompat(mContext, mMediaBrowserCompat.getSessionToken());
            mMediaController.registerCallback(mMediaControllerCompatCallback);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Do those users have your activity in the foreground at the time the playback stops? By my read of the `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` source code, it's used purely as a bound service. As such, this service might not be contributing towards keeping your process running in the background. See [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice#service-lifecycle) and [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice#mediastyle-notifications) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe the activity is in the background as the stoppage happens after a couple minutes. The biggest issue is that it's not happening for everyone. I'll have to get more info from the users. I really just wanted to verify that updating the `SeekBar` this way wouldn't cause issues because it's running every 250 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case it helps anyone in the future but connecting to a `MediaBrowserService` does not actually start the service. You have to call `startService` in the `MediaBrowserService` (the documentation recommends when playback starts) or the `MediaBrowserService` will stop when all connections to it disconnect.